# Time deference between two date("F j, Y") dates in php

Tags: php, date, time, date-math

i have a problem to get month difference between two dates in months.

```
$d1 = date_create('January 1, 2013');
$date = date("F j, Y");
$d2 = date_create($date);
$dif = date_diff($d1, $d2);
 //echo $dif->format('%y years');
 echo $dif->format('%m months');
```

It shows months but not the whole difference in months. I just want the diff in months between dates.

Comment: This code out put '10 months' but the real differnce is 22 months.

Comment: what 'date("F j, Y")' stands for? Why don't you print the second date.

Comment: It show current date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%m` only shows up to 11 months. After that years are populated. If you want total months you need to figure in years and do some math:

```
$d1  = date_create('January 1, 2013');
$d2  = date_create();
$dif = date_diff($d1, $d2);
echo ($dif->format('%m') + $dif->format('%y') * 12) . ' months';
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/216854)

FYI, the above solution removes unnecessary code. If you want today's date you just don't pass any parameters to `date_create()`.